# Neat way to check User Group Levels?

Tags: php, authentication, security

What is the neat soluton to check user group level to do certain tasks

Groups: 2 Admin, 3 Moderators, 4 Process Orders

Let assume `data['user']['group_id']` is 3

I came up with this Solution.

Solution 1:

```
$allowGroup = array(2, 3, 4);
if (in_array($this->data['user']['group_id'], $allowGroup)) {
    //Show a list of records
    if ($this->data['user']['group_id'] == 2) {
      //Show buttons to delete records (only admin can do this)
     }
}
```

Solution 2:

```
if (($this->data['user']['group_id'] == 3) || ($this->data['user']['group_id'] == 4)) {
      //Member can do this action..
}
```

Comment: i think using switch ( ) will be more faster for only 3 choices

Comment: "Better" is a request for a subjective answer. Can you rephrase your question to tell us exactly how you hope to fix or improve your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly more efficient, but less readable method would be to specify your "allowed" levels as the array keys. Then it's a simple array lookup, without having to call in_array(), which would do a (more) expensive loop:

```
$rawAllow = array(2,3,4);
$allowed = array_flip($rawAllow);

if (isset($allowed[$this->data['user']['group_id']])) {
   ... this user is allowed to perform the action...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, In the if condition, sometime I only want admin to see Delete link only (group 2), what is your solution to that?

Comment: You'd need arrays listing permissions for all the various actions you want to filter on. Basically, ACLs (access control lists).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: [Bitwise Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

With that you could do something like (be aware this is a very basic example!):

```
<?php
// example actions
$actions = array(
    'create'    => 1,
    'read'      => 2,
    'update'    => 4,
    'delete'    => 8,
);

// example groups
$groups = array(
    // Admins
    2 => $actions['create'] ^ $actions['read'] ^ $actions['update'] ^ $actions['delete'],

    // Moderators
    3 => $actions['create'] ^ $actions['read'] ^ $actions['update'],

    // Process Orders
    4 => $actions['read'] ^ $actions['update'],
);

// example users
$users = array(
    // Admin
    (object)array(
        'id' => 1,
        'groupId' => 2, 
    ),

    // Moderator
    (object)array(
        'id' => 2,
        'groupId' => 3, 
    ),

    // Process Order
    (object)array(
        'id' => 3,
        'groupId' => 4,
    ),
);

foreach ($users as $user) {
    if (isset($groups[$user->groupId])) {
        printf('User: %s is allowed to: ' . "\n", $user->id);   

        if ($groups[$user->groupId] & $actions['create']) {
            echo ' create';
        }

        if ($groups[$user->groupId] & $actions['read']) {
            echo ' read';
        }

        if ($groups[$user->groupId] & $actions['update']) {
            echo ' update';
        }

        if ($groups[$user->groupId] & $actions['delete']) {
            echo ' delete';
        }

        echo "\n\n";
    }
}
```